# Hollow Mesh with Grid Surface

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a model of a mountain that we want to use for 3d printing, however we want it to be a "wire frame / grid like" mesh when printed so its full of holes where plants can grow out of

Thoughts?

Comment: How about giving a thickness to your model by 'Solidify' modifier, and make the holes in appropriate places with Boolean. You need to be sure that your mesh is watertight at the end though.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It could help if you add some images of what you'd like to achieve because e.g. do you want all the mountain to be wireframe-like or only certain parts, how big those holes should be and should they be located only where plants are supposed to be or not etc.